# Is there anyway to make an executable compatible by using matlab mex?

Tags: matlab, mex

The executable is created by using mex. Currently I tried it on windows, but eventually I will need it for windows, linux, and mac os x.

The problem is it can only be used with the same version of matlab which I used to create it. 
The main reason I think is if different version of matlab is used, then the path for libraries used by the executable will be different.

Is there any way that I can create an executable from mex which can be compatible with different versions of matlab?

Is possible that I set paths for libraries and header files associated with multiple versions of matlab?

Please correct me if I understand anything wrong above. Thanks a lot.

More detail information:

The way to generate my executable is to call:

```
mex('-v', '-f', [matlabroot '\bin\win32\mexopts\msvc90engmatopts.bat'], 'myexecutable.cpp');
```

In the msvc90engmatopts.bat file, paths are set for librarires and header files and etc.
msvc90engmatopts.bat is from matlab.

Comment: You might play with  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. But you don't give enough details about the libraries needed by matlab. And you could consider using [scilab](http://www.scilab.org/) (instead of matlab).

Comment: please check my update, thanks. Regarding to the libraries called by the executable, I am not very such which libraries are needed. Because they all can be found in the path. I guess the way to do it is to give all paths for different versions of matlab.

Comment: Of course `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a Linux (or Posix) thing. You should have tagged your operating system specific question with the proprietary operating system you are using.

Comment: yes, platform, currently, I tried it for windows. Eventually, I will need it for win, linux, and mac os x.

Comment: By versions do you mean R2014a vs. R2013b or Windows vs. Linux?

Comment: means: r2014a vs r2013a and other versions.